# How to pull an entire row of data in R using only one column's value

Tags: r

I'm working with a big data set and want to create a value that is based on multiple variables (columns) from a single observation (row). The observation the value is based on needs to have the minimum value of the data set for one of the variables which is how I can identify the observation.

Is there a way I can create this value without looking manually by telling R to pull the variables I need from whatever row has the minimum value of a different variable?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I don't understand what you mean by "looking manually". It sounds like standard data selection with `[` would work, like `mtcars[which(mtcars$disp==min(mtcars$disp)), c("mpg","wt")]`. But maybe you mean something else?

Comment: `mtcars[which.min(mtcars$disp), c("mpg","wt")]` is a bit simpler, but in either case there could be more than one row with the minimum value.

Comment: These are exactly what I needed! Now is there a way to concatenate "mpg" and "wt" into a value without creating the vector first?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, it's almost certainly possible to do whatever calculation you want all at once, but whether it's simpler/easier is another question. Either way, you'd need to explain what the calculation is for us to suggest anything.